# Absolute position on flexbox element

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to right-align an absolute element (`#header-supporter-cont`) (absolute to overlap an image) with a 1.5% right margin within a max-width container of 1280px. This'd be pretty easy if it were a relative element, but as absolute, I haven't been able to achieve this.

As a side note, I'm trying to do this in flexbox because simply setting `right: 1.5%`, as I originally did, doesn't align the content in `#header-supporter-cont` with the rest of the page's 1280px horizontal margins since it counts from edge to edge.

HTML:

```
<header id="header">
  <div id="header-cont">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=44&txt=Header%20Image&w=1920&h=200" /></a>
    <div id="header-supporter-cont">
      <div id="header-supporter">
        <div id="header-supporter-text">
          Image text here
        </div>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.aexp-static.com/nav/ngn/img/logo_bluebox_1x.gif" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
#header #header-cont a {
  display: block;
}
#header #header-cont a img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
#header #header-cont #header-supporter-cont {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 1.5%;
  position: relative;
}
#header #header-cont #header-supporter-cont #header-supporter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 0;
}
#header #header-cont #header-supporter-cont #header-supporter #header-supporter-text {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
#header #header-cont #header-supporter-cont #header-supporter #header-supporter-text span {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
#header #header-cont #header-supporter-cont #header-supporter a {
  display: block;
}
#header #header-cont #header-supporter-cont #header-supporter a img {
  width: 55px;
}
```

Demos:

- Original, non-flexbox: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/ggoebB
- Non-functioning flexbox: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/oBpqqy

Comment: The only difference I see in 2 pens is the position of text.

Comment: @Pangloss Yes, in the first, it looks close to what I'm trying to achieve, but the right margin is off; in the second, I tried using flexbox, but it doesn't look right at all. Sorry, I forgot to mention this is in relation to `#header-supporter`.

Comment: Change #header-supporter from flex-direction row to column.

Comment: @Pangloss That addresses placing the text above the image, but I'm trying to move the text and image to the right together, like in the first Pen.

Comment: Set absolute on #header-supporter-count directly http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKxyVN

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/apEGyP

Comment: @Pangloss This is closer, the reason I set it on `#header-supporter` and not `#header-supporter-cont` is because `#header-supporter-cont` needs a max-width of 1280px.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Minus 3%, not plus, gives me the right overall positioning, but now the text is next to the image, instead of above.

Comment: Just change the flex-direction mentioned above if everything else works.

Comment: oh right, sorry -3%. I thought @Pangloss said "Change #header-supporter from flex-direction row to column." Does that not work for putting the text above the image?

Comment: @MichaelCoker @Pangloss Yep, that did it. Thanks, guys! I forgot about `calc`.

Comment: Great, but mixing pixels, percentage and calc just for that 1.5% gap sounds overdoing it, I suggest to reconsider the design.

Comment: @Pangloss The design came from a designer, which is already approved, so I don't have any flexibility there. I could stick to pixels, but then it wouldn't be as responsive. If you can think of a better method to implement a 1.5% horizontal padding within a 1280px container, I'm more than happy to hear you out.

Comment: Understood, since it's working now I wouldn't try more for it.

Comment: Hmm I just noticed that this doesn't work when the viewport is smaller than 1280px since it doesn't subtract 3% then. Trying to figure out how to apply a universal rule without using a media query...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your flex direction for `flex-direction: column;`

```
#header-supporter {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: flex-end;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 20px;
                right: 0;}
```